# Java universal commands

Tags: java, shutdown, universal

I'm writing a application which I would like to be able to do certain tasks with the computer.

As an example I could use:

```
runCommand("shutdown.exe", "-s -t 01");
```

to shutdown, but that would only work if the program is executed on Windows XP or later.

Is there a way to make Java perform some tasks that are universal and will work on every operating system that has Java installed? Like the shutdown command.

Comment: You'll have to call many different functions specific to many different OS. And you'll have to deal with permissions, too.

Comment: If you can hook into 'ACPI shutdown', that would be the only way that I would guess might work.  Try it in VirtualBox to see it in action.

Comment: Do you seriously need to support anything **before** Windows XP? I doubt you'll actually find a working Java Runtime for those ancient beasts (maybe for Windows 2000, but I doubt that - definitely not for any of the DOS based systems like Windows 95/98/ME).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: anything before XP is probably not support-worthy, but something *besides Windows* might be.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Why aren't smileys not allowed to stay ? :-) I would like to know if i should keep away from them when I'm here :-)

Comment: @DSDeniso: it's not that smiles are not allowed to stay, but here on SO we value [precise, compact information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles) (both in questions and answers). So anything that distracts from the "meat" of the question is discouraged. That's also why I removed the "All help is appreciated" (which is implicit if you ask a question). I wouldn't have edited if it were just for the smilies.

Comment: @DSDeniso: anything *besides* Windows will require a completely different command anyway.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks, everything is now clear :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No. Commands like the one in the example are absolutely specific to the host operating system, and are not portable across platforms. You'll find *some* degree of compatibility among related OSs, for example in POSIX-compliant Unix operating systems

Comment: And you don't think that it would be possible to make the ACPI shutdown like @djangofan said?

Comment: @DSDeniso: while ACPI itself is pretty well-standardized, I don't think there's a universal OS-level API to *access* ACPI at all (since usually only the OS itself is interested in ACPI-calls). So I seriously doubt this is possible.

Comment: @DSDeniso it'll be hard to access such a low level command from Java, and you'll have to dive in native code at some point

Comment: Okay thanks, voted up and answer will be accepted in 7 minutes :-)

Comment: By the way, does Java have some other cool functions that is universal? Just wondering :-)

Comment: @DSDeniso If by "universal" you mean "portable across platforms" yes, for example all the file-related functionality, and thread handling. This can be done because there exists native code in each platform implementing that functionality